# General Question about Swing Components

Tags: java, user-interface, swing

I was wondering how swing components themselves are actually made. It seems like a JComboBox is made up of a JButton and when you click it, a JList appears below it. Is that the general way the components are made. Are components themselves made up of smaller components? If this is the case, then how are the smallest components actually created? Like a JLabel or JButton.

This would lead me to the analogy that JLabel and JTextField are like the int and double primitives in java.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can always look up the source of the components at [Google Code Search](http://www.google.com/codesearch?q=JCheckBox) and see how the components are made.

Answer (score 0):

Some of the components might be made using other components, or built around the older AWT components. But in the end, all GUI functionality has to be based on some platform-dependent functionality in the VM, so e.g. in Windows, if you trace through all the layers of indirection, you'll eventually come down to calls for the [Windows GDI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd145203%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) at some point.

Answer (score 0):

The first GUI toolkit in java was AWT.
AWT provided its functionality by calling native libraries to display the GUI components.
Swing's component's on the other hand (Swing was introduced along with Java2D) do not correspond to native components.
Swing's components are drawn using Java2D and allow the programmer to customize the drawing  so that applications can have the look the programmer wants.
One of the benefits of this is to allow for platform interoperability (since it does not need to check which native libraries are available to delegate) as well as provide extra widgets not present in native libraries.